# Getting unwanted and duplicate blocks in tensorboard but not in model.summary()

Tags: graph, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am using a CNN architecture and adding few more layers in between and creating a new model. By using model.summary() on this new model, I see everything is aligned fine but in tensorboard, I am seeing duplicate blocks connected around with new blocks.Kind of new network parallely drawn with the old network block and some connection in between.

I am using tensorboard = Tensorboard() for the tensorboard in keras.

Please advise why I see these connections and old network blocks in parallel with new model blocks but on the other hand model.summary() looks totally fine.

I am trying to understand so any detail on this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue.
The main reason for this is, whenever the model is created, every layer gets a new name. For example: if you have a model with two 2d-convolutional layers followed by a dense layer. Creating the model for the 1st time and executing `model.Summary()`, results in the below layer names:

- conv2d_1
- conv2d_2
- dense_1

While re-executing the same code, yields:

- conv2d_3
- conv2d_4
- dense_2

At the same time, the logs that Tensor-board uses are overwritten. Hence, parallel blocks of layers with different names appears.

Comment: In my case, I am using a CNN architecture, and taking its layers and creating a new model. Because of this I see new layers as well as this particular architecture layers. When I am trying to use these layers by copying its layers in a list somehow the old layers from architectures are connected with new layers. On the other hand my model.summary() looks correct. Should I trust the model.summary() or the tensorboard output. Please advise.

Comment: Trust the model.summary()

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to verify it with some external tool.